# New Kendo Data Source is null?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-datasource

So I have an Array which is defined like this

```
var newArrary = Array();
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   if (result[i].Id != TaskId) {
       newArrary.push({text:result[i].Name, value:result[i].Id})
   }
}
```

I did a console.log and can see that the array got initialize correctly.
[image]

I then went on to create a new data Source

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: newArrary
    });
```

and also check and see that it is initialize correctly

[image]

but when I try to set it to a dropdownlist with the `setDataSource` method on my drop down list it complains about `Uncaught TypeError: Text.indexOf is not a function`

So I did a simple `dataSource.at(1)` and get 'undefined'. Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE Adding more code:**

How I Created/Configured the drop down

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
              .BindTo(list)
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .HtmlAttributes(attributes)
              .OptionLabel(string.IsNullOrEmpty(label) ? (required && @dropDownList.Value != "0" && @dropDownList.Value != "" ? "" : " ") : label)
              .Value(@dropDownList.Value)
              .TemplateId("myTemplate")
              .ValueTemplateId("dmyTemplate")
        )
```

And how I am using the the setDatasource

```
setTask = function (result, taskCodeStartList, taskCodeResultLisr) {
    var selectedTaskItem = $("#" + taskStartList).data("kendoDropDownList")
    var selectedFilterTask = $("#" + taskResultLisr).data("kendoDropDownList").value()
    var newArrary = Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].Id != selectedFilterTaskId) {
            newArrary.push({text:result[i].Name, value:result[i].Id})
        }
    }

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: newArrary
    });

    selectedTaskCodeItem.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return selectedTaskCodeItem;
};
```

Comment: Please provide the DropDownList configuration and how and where you are using `setDataSource`. A complete example with dummy `result` will be most useful.

Comment: @dimodi I am using the Kendo MVC so i can't really create a working example but I can post more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataTextField` and `dataValueField` settings are with capital letters (`"Text"`, `"Value"`), but the `newArrary` items have fields with lowercase letters (`text`, `value`). These should match, otherwise the widget will not be able to handle the new data.

http://dojo.telerik.com/OQOle

I am not sure about the

> So I did a simple dataSource.at(1) and get 'undefined'.

part, as everything else looks OK.